# alexa rank didn't work for me since 3 or 4 days

Tags: php, json, api, rank, alexa-skills-kit

hello i have a website fetching data from alexa 
bat since two or 3 days its return nothing i don't know if alexa changed something or ...

some of code that i have  traied
so i ask alexa experts to guide me

i hope that any one have some help

```
<?
$url='toolspot.org';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
$web=(string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
echo $web." has Alexa Rank ".$rank;
?>
```

second code

```
<?php

class Get_Alexa_Ranking{

    /**
     * Get the rank from alexa for the given domain
     * 
     * @param $domain
     * The domain to search on
     */
    public function get_rank($domain){

        $url = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=".$domain;

        //Initialize the Curl  
        $ch = curl_init();  

        //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2); 

        //Set the URL  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  

        //Execute the fetch  
        $data = curl_exec($ch);  

        //Close the connection  
        curl_close($ch);  

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);  

                //Get popularity node
        $popularity = $xml->xpath("//POPULARITY");

                //Get the Rank attribute
        $rank = (string)$popularity[0]['TEXT']; 

        return $rank;
    }

}
?>
    //Include alexa ranking class
require_once 'get_alexa_ranking.php';

//Create a new object
$alexa = new Get_Alexa_Ranking();

//Get the rank for the domain paulund.co.uk
echo "Rank ".$alexa->get_rank("elhawd.com");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Alexa is not returning anymore the traffic data.

I have checked several domains and someones returns error and someones some data without traffic numbers.

Example:
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=terra.com
Returns:

```
<!--
 Need more Alexa data?  Find our APIs here: https://aws.amazon.com/alexa/ 
-->
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="terra.com/" HOME="0" AID="=" IDN="terra.com/">
<RLS PREFIX="http://" more="0">
<RL HREF="univision.com/" TITLE="Univision"/>
<RL HREF="terra.es/" TITLE="Terra"/>
<RL HREF="terra.com.pr/" TITLE="Terra - Informaci&oacute;n Para Hispanos, Noticias En Espa&ntilde;ol, Mu"/>
<RL HREF="terra.com.pe/" TITLE="Terra"/>
<RL HREF="terra.com.mx/" TITLE="Terra México"/>
<RL HREF="terra.com.gt/" TITLE="Terra Guatemala"/>
<RL HREF="terra.com.co/" TITLE="Terra Networks Colombia"/>
<RL HREF="terra.com.ar/" TITLE="Terra Argentina"/>
<RL HREF="telemundo.com/" TITLE="Telemundo"/>
<RL HREF="pronto.com/" TITLE="Pronto Progress"/>
</RLS>
<SD TITLE="A" FLAGS="" HOST="terra.com">
<TITLE TEXT="Terra"/>
<OWNER NAME="Terra Network, S.A."/>
</SD>
</ALEXA>
```

I think the solution is to pay alexa for this data

Answer (score 0):

I am using their API service (the proper way of accessing Alexa data) and since march 13th it stopped returning data. I hope this is only temporary, since nothing about changes was posted on relevant sites, including Amazon AWS.

Update 14/03: API method is fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think it was just a temporary issue now it came back

maintenant elle march acce succes

الآن تشتغل

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I works fine now, you can test it:
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=stackoverflow.com